# Woocommerce out-of-stock button with contact form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

We are having a webshop and I would like to add a button on every out-of-stock product page. I've been using this code, but I'm missing a piece as the button is on every product now (also the available products). Can anyone help me with this question?

Thank you!

```
// Adds a enquiry form on your Woocommerce Single product page

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'enquiry_form', 30 ); 
function enquiry_form() { echo '<button type="submit" id="trigger_cf" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Vraag de prijs op</button>'; echo '<div id="product_inq" style="display:none">'; echo do_shortcode('[wpforms id="1372"]'); echo '</div>'; } 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'enquiry_form_1', 40);
function enquiry_form_1() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#trigger_cf').on('click', function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).text() == 'Vraag de prijs op' ) {
                jQuery('#product_inq').css("display","block");
        jQuery("#trigger_cf").html('Sluit');
    } else {
        jQuery('#product_inq').hide();
        jQuery("#trigger_cf").html('Vraag de prijs op');
    }
    });
</script>
<?php    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So by adding `global $product;` and using this code `get_post_meta( $product->ID, '_stock_status', true );` to get the stock status of the product, You can then toss in an if statement that checks of the product is in stock or not. and if its in stock you can then run your code that places a button.

Try this code and see if it works for you:

```
// Adds a enquiry form on your Woocommerce Single product page

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'enquiry_form', 30 ); 
function enquiry_form() { 
global $product;
$stockStatus = get_post_meta( $product->ID, '_stock_status', true );

if ($stockStatus == "outofstock"){
echo '<button type="submit" id="trigger_cf" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Vraag de prijs op</button>';
echo '<div id="product_inq" style="display:none">'; echo do_shortcode('[wpforms id="1372"]');
echo '</div>'; } 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'enquiry_form_1', 40);
function enquiry_form_1() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#trigger_cf').on('click', function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).text() == 'Vraag de prijs op' ) {
                jQuery('#product_inq').css("display","block");
        jQuery("#trigger_cf").html('Sluit');
    } else {
        jQuery('#product_inq').hide();
        jQuery("#trigger_cf").html('Vraag de prijs op');
    }
    });
</script>
<?php    
}
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much for your reply! I've added the snippet, but unfortunately the button isn't showing (see for example: https://www.hc-systems.nl/product/airco-leiding-1-4-3-8-x-20-meter/)

Comment: @Grow123JV I apologize, my answer had a very simple mistake that I missed.  I have updated the code in my answer. please try it again.

Comment: Hi John, again thank you so much for your reply! The button is still not showing, however I tried I've tried to switch the rule code to: if( $var_stock_count <= 0 ) { The button was showing but now the button was showing on every article (also on products with a stock). Maybe there's something in my webshop?